# How to run wordpress v 4.2 with php 7.0

Tags: wordpress, php-7, php-5.5

I have a wordpress project version 4.2 with php v5.5
I want to run this project in my localhost where I have php 7.0
How to do update?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @A.Sana.You have to downgrade a PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your local dev environment using Local by Flywheel. Local includes the option to choose which version of PHP to use when setting up a site. https://local.getflywheel.com/